# What do I do when I find a dimension entrance in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I found something that looks like a stone structure. Maybe a dungeon?

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? It's rather unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I use my Xbox 1s

Comment: That kind of looks like a Fortress... that some how generated at the surface level.. But since I have not played the XBox1 version in quite some time and have never seen how (if?) they generate a fortress... Dunno :D Explore it.. if you find a room like the one on this page: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/End_portal its a fortress and contains well, the end portal....

Answer (score 3):

This is a Stronghold. These structures house, as @James said, an end portal. To use it however, you must first find it!

The Stronghold is a labyrinth within a labyrinth. It is super easy to get lost. 
Once you finally find it, you'll need to fill the portal's slots with Eyes of Ender. They are crafted by putting an Ender pearl and a piece of Blaze powder together.

Finally, enter in! You will encounter a new enemy I will let you discover for yourself!

Comment: N.B.: If you don't want spoilers, don't look Minecraft up online at least until you've got to the "Ender" place.